# How to setup RealVNC Server Home subscription without GUI on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, realvnc

I acquired the .deb file from https://www.realvnc.com/download/file/vnc.files/VNC-Server-6.7.1-Linux-x64.deb. I installed using dpkg. I cannot add a license key as I have a home subscription. I only have SSH access for now. How would I login to RealVNC?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to install another VNC package.  Then, connect to the host using a VNC client and run the RealVNC configuration using the GUI.

For some situations (such as for me, using a Raspberry Pi with preinstalled RealVNC server, but where I had the same situation as you did), I used ssh port forwarding to tunnel the VNC connection to my host, ran the RealVNC configuration to register my Home account to the web service, and then was able to use RealVNC via the web as usual.

Here's an example that worked using a Pi that had IP 192.168.1.8:

ssh -L 5900:192.168.1.8:5900 pi@192.168.1.8

One you've authenticated and are connected successfully, use VNC Connect (or another VNC tool) to make a direct connection to the target, as follows:

1. Open VNC on your source host.
2. Connect to 127.0.0.1 (your loopback address). You are connecting to the same, source system. (Note: You should NOT have VNC server listening on port 5900 when you do this. If you do, specify a port other than 5900 as the first value of the -L parameter.)
3. You should connect to the the target host.

If you are having issues, check the /var/log/vncserver-xll.log on the target host for useful troubleshooting hints.